# how to use a username and password for mosquitto_new c/c++ mqtt

Tags: c++, c, mosquitto, libmosquitto

Hi so I am using linux (ubuntu) and I am using c/c++ with the libmosquitto mqtt library. There is a function called mosquitto_new() that takes the client id, cleas_session and a void object pointer as the arguments. In all the examples I have seen online the void object pointer parameter has been left as NULL meaning that no username or password was required. I did see online that if you want to use a username and password then you change the void pointer object from NULL to a pointer to your username and password.

But I dont understand how that works, because if you had your username and password in the code it kinda defeats the point of having a password.

I know that from testing if you just use the terminal to use the mosquitto mqtt broker then you make a text file that has the username and password and change the .conf file to not allow anonymous users and enable the username and password file.
But I am unsure how to do this in c/c++ using the mosquitto library.

So overall if anyone has any idea how to do this I would greatly appreciate the help, I think it is to do with changing the NULL in the mosquitto_new function but am unsure.

Attached is my code for the publisher that I have working atm if it is any help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include </home/dave/mosquitto/include/mosquitto.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
      int rc;
      char message[] = "Hello World testing";
      
      struct mosquitto * mosq;

      mosquitto_lib_init();
      

      mosq = mosquitto_new("publisher-test", true, NULL);

      rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, "130.246.57.26", 1883, 60); // ip 130.246.57.26
      if(rc != 0){
            printf("Client could not connect to broker! Error Code: %d\n", rc);
            mosquitto_destroy(mosq);
            return -1;
      }
      printf("We are now connected to the broker!\n");

      mosquitto_publish(mosq, NULL, "test/1", sizeof(message), &message , 0, false);

      mosquitto_disconnect(mosq);
      mosquitto_destroy(mosq);

      mosquitto_lib_cleanup();
      return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Dean

Comment: What, exactly, did you "see online"? What did it say? I was not familiar with this library, but a simple keyword search found this library's technical documentation. including that of `mosquitto_new`, which plainly stated that the third `void *` parameter has absolutely nothing to do, whatsoever, with any userid or password. Don't you think that it makes a lot more sense to actually read the technical documentation of the library, go straight to the source, instead of running random keyword searches, for second-hand, hearsay information?

Comment: ... and mosquitto.org's technical documentation, for their library, clearly named the function that sets the userid and the password, and explained all the requirements for doing so. I found mosquitto.org's documentation to be one of the easier ones to read, can't be any simpler. Now, try reading libxml's documentation... Brrrr.....

Comment: Could you tell me which function sets the userid and password or provide a link, I am not a programmer so I just find it harder to read the documentation. Was the website mosquitto.org/api

Comment: Yes, that's where I found everything, specifically https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html -- but it's not realistic to expect to be able to use a modestly non-trivial software library without a development background. I would estimate, based on what I read, that one needs to have about 3-5 years of C++ experience, in order to be able to effectively use a software library of this level of complexity.

Comment: `struct mosquitto * mosq;` -- The `struct` is not required in a C++ program.  Just `mosquitto * mosq;`.  Also C and C++ are two separate languages, but you tagged both of them.  There is no `<iostream>` in the C language.  Having a mix of this indicates an uncertainty of the language you are using to develop and/or lack of experience in C++, but using C as a model in writing C++ code (which is not good).

Answer (score 1):

The correct section of the documentation is [here](https://mosquitto.org/api/files/mosquitto-h.html#Username_and_password) which discusses the `mosquitto_username_pw_set` function which is used to update the `mosq` struct with the username/password before `mosquitto_connect` is called.

e.g.

```
      struct mosquitto * mosq;
      mosquitto_lib_init();

      mosq = mosquitto_new("publisher-test", true, NULL);
      mosquitto_username_pw_set(mosq, "username", "password")

      rc = mosquitto_connect(mosq, "130.246.57.26", 1883, 60);
```